# Getting a crash while creating the substring in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, string, substring, bidirectional

While creating the string offset, getting a rare crash as:

```
specialized specialized _BidirectionalIndexable.index(A.Index, offsetBy : A.IndexDistance) -> A.Index**
```

Here is my code:

```
let cloud_data ="2332333223325#"
let data_substring = "test-" + cloud_data.substring(from:cloud_data.index(cloud_data.endIndex, offsetBy: -4))
```

This is the above code, which using for the getting the substring. The line number 73, is the above one. Attached the log screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Can it happen that the string `cloud_data` has less than 4 characters?

Comment: @MartinR cloud_data will be always above 10 characters.

Comment: Then I don't see how *that* code could crash. – A simpler and safer variant would be `let data_substring = "test-" + cloud_data.suffix(4)`, but that does not explain the crash if the string has at least 4 characters.

Comment: @MartinR ```data_substring = "test-" + cloud_data.suffix(4)```, i think this will be much safer.

Comment: @Joe Your code is not getting crashed anyway. Output is `test-325#`.

Comment: Maybe a stupid question, what is the .substring(...) method on String? Is it in your own extension to String because I can't find it in the documentation and if so can you post the code?

Comment: I found the answer to my question, this is not Swift 4.

Comment: @Joe Have you found the cause or a solution for this crash?